# How to cycle through search suggestion (search bar) in Firefox 48 using TAB key

Tags: firefox

Is there any what to cycle through the search suggestions in the search bar using Firefox v48?

This was possible in earlies version of Firefox. However when I now hit the `tab` key, I can only cycle through different search engines, even tough I have all but one search engine disabled. Only way to select different suggestion now is using the up and down arrows.

Some people on the Internet suggest to set `browser.search.showOneOffButtons` to `false` but unfortunately this option has been removed from Firefox.

Comment: What is the problem with using up and dorn arrows to cycle through the search suggestions?