# How do I customize the keyboard shortcut that cycles through Firefox search suggestions?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

When searching for something in the Firefox browser, I want to customize the keybindings to cycle through the pop up suggestions (see picture for reference). In Chrome, I use `Control-n` for down, and `Control-p` for up.

In Firefox, what are these keybindings called, and how can I customize them? The default settings are the `up` and `down` arrow keys, which I don't prefer because I have to leave the home row of the keyboard. For reference, I am on MacOS High Sierra and using Firefox Quantum 62.0.2 (64-bit).

[image: screenshot example]

For context, [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1113719/how-to-cycle-through-search-suggestion-search-bar-in-firefox-48-using-tab-key) exists already, but didn't get any traction.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know of would be to to use a 3rd party tool like [autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/). Mozilla FF doesn't allow custom keyboard shortcuts (yet).